# How do I make a method return a generic method?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am creating a repository as follows:

```
public class StagingRepository
{
    private IRepository<CurrentTransformer> CurrentTransformerRepository { get; set; }
    private IRepository<Equipment> EquipmentRepository { get; set; }
    private IRepository<Line> LineRepository { get; set; }
    public StagingRepository()
    {
        this.CurrentTransformerRepository = new Repository<CurrentTransformer>();
        this.EquipmentRepository = new Repository<Equipment>();
        this.LineRepository = new Repository<Line>();
    }
}
```

All this works... however what I am trying to add is a method within the class that returns one of the Repositories above based on a string value.

```
public IRepository<Object> SetRepo(string TableName)
{
    switch (TableName)
    {
        case "Line":
            return LineRepository;
            break;
    }
}
```

I know the above does not work but it gives you an idea of what I am trying to accomplish. My goal would be I should be able to setup something like this in my code to call the repository:

```
StagingRepository _repo = new StagingRepository();
var myList = _repo.SetRepo("Line").All(); //All is a function of IRepository
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `IRepository` [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx):

```
public interface IRepository<out T>
```

This way, you can always use `IRepository<Derived>` in place of `IRepository<Base>` when returning from a method. In your case, your code will now compile and work:

```
public IRepository<object> SetRepo(string TableName)
{
    switch (TableName)
    {
        case "Line":
            return LineRepository;
            break;
    }
}
```

because `Line` is derived from `object`, so you can return `IRepository<Line>` for `IRepository<object>`.

This however won't work if you use `T` as an argument - type can not be both covariant and contravariant. In such case, consider moving non-generic methods from `IRepository<T>` to a non-generic version `IRepository` and make your repositories implement both. This way you could have:

```
public IRepository SetRepo(string TableName)
// ...
```

By the way, the name `SetRepo` is misleading - the function doesn't set anything, it rather "gets" an appropriate repository.

Comment: @kevinc I've added more explanations. Is it OK now?

Comment: I tried to put in IRepository<out t> however it will not allow due to I have other methods that are requiring T

Comment: @kevinc Indeed, that's a problem - a type can't be both covariant and contravariant. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @kevinc Sorry, nothing better than this (not counting reflection-overkill approaches) came to my mind.

Comment: I guess I do not understand what you mean by making generic and non-generic. Can you help?

Comment: @kevinc If you have some methods in `IRepository<T>` that do not depend on `T` then you can move these methods to `IRepository`, and make `IRepository<T>` inherit them (from `IRepository`).